# Integral Computation

Tags: calculus

Consider $$\frac{1}{x-y} = \int_{1}^{\infty} t^{y-x} \frac{dt}{t}$$

If we want to calculate $\log(x-y)$ from this expression then we would do the following:

$$\log \left(\frac{1}{x-y} \right) = \log \left(\int_{1}^{\infty} t^{y-x} \frac{dt}{t} \right)$$

$$ \Longleftrightarrow \log(x-y) = -\log \left(\int_{1}^{\infty} t^{y-x} \frac{dt}{t} \right)$$

$$= -\log \left(\frac{1}{-y+x-1} \right)$$

> Is this the same as $$ \log(x-y) = -\int_{1}^{\infty} t^{y-x-1} \frac{dt}{\log t}$$

**Note.** I am talking about this in a formal sense. Convergence issues are not an issue for the moment.

This is how I reached the second line: $$ \log \left(\frac{1}{x-y} \right) = \text{something}$$ $$\Longleftrightarrow \log(1)-\log(x-y) = \text{something}$$

$$ \Longleftrightarrow \log(x-y) = - \text{something} $$

**Added.** This is Terence Tao's [notes](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/the-riemann-hypothesis-in-various-settings/#comment-239343) after Equation 3.

Comment: Please go back and look at what you write more carefully.  The analysis leads to an impossibility.  Also, for what values of $x$ and $y$ does the integral even converge?

Comment: Are you really saying that $\log(x-y)=\log(x-y-1)$? There is something wrong with that.

Comment: You have the same integral in line 3 that you had in line 1, yet you've given it a different value? Also note for line 1 that the integral only converges for x > y.

Comment: It also is not clear what an improper integral equality means "in a formal sense."

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the needed "formal sense", but I would add a small remark to those already contained in the comments.
The equality

$$\frac{1}{x-y}=\int_1^{+\infty}t^{y-x}\frac{dt}{t}$$

holds if $y-x<0$. In this case the r.h.s. gives

$$\int_1^{+\infty}t^{y-x}\frac{dt}{t}=\int_1^{\infty}t^{y-x-1}dt=
\frac{t^{y-x}}{y-x}|^{+\infty}_1=-\frac{1}{y-x}=\frac{1}{x-y},$$

as $t^{q}\rightarrow 0$ for $t\rightarrow +\infty$ if $q<0$.